# Question about counter-argument to Cantor's Diagonalization Argument.

Tags: real-analysis

For one of my homework assignments I was given the following complaints about his argument:

Every rational number has a decimal expansion so we could apply the Cantor Diagonalization Argument to show that the set of rational numbers between 0 and 1 is also uncountable.However, because we know that any subset of Q must be countable, there must be a flaw in Cantor’s Diagonalization Argument.

My idea is that the flaws in this argument are the following: 
Firstly, the set of numbers between 0 and 1 does not only consist of rationals - there are irrational numbers as well. Therefore, the argument that the set of numbers between 0 and 1 is rational and therefore countable is incorrect. However, I might be misunderstanding the problem because it is talking about the set of rationals between 0 and 1 specifically, so I'm just generally confused.

Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Edit: 
After reading the comments, I understand my initial thoughts above were incorrect. So, since this is looking at the rationals in the set (0,1), would I be correct in saying that if we used Cantor's method, there is no way of ensuring that the diagonal taken would also be a rational (since a rational can be written as a repeating decimal expansion). Since the diagonal might not ever repeat (because in theory, each added number in the diagonal can continue infinitely and never repeat). Would this argument be correct?

Comment: You are misreading the question. The statement is not that "the set of numbers between $0$ and $1$ is rational and therefore countable," but rather that "the set of rational numbers between $0$ and $1$ is countable."

Comment: The argument is: “take all **rational** numbers between $0$ and $1$. Create a list of them. Apply Cantor’s Diagonalization argument to this list, and thus exhibit a rational between $0$ and $1$ that is not in your original list. Thus, the collection of rational numbers between $0$ and $1$ is uncountable.”   Your “firstly” is then nonsense; while correct in your assertion, that assertion is irrelevant because you are not asserting all numbers in $(0,1)$ are rationals.  The real problem with the ‘argument’ proposed is elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, your new reasoning is correct. Well done! (You could write this up as an answer below.)